# Memory allocation for int array, set in method

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am quite new in C and I have a question about understanding one memory allocation issue:

So lets say I allocate memory for an int array:

```
 int* my_array = malloc(sizeof(int)*10);
```

Now I know that a memory block of the given size has been allocated at position '&my_array[0]' (or just my_array).

SO:

If I know call a method to fill my array, I KNOW I should give as a parameter the pointer to my array in order to fill it, so something like:

```
void fill_array(int* array) {//..do something}
fill_array(my_array);
```

But I was wondering, what would happen, if the method itself allocates another memory block and I then try to set those equal, so what I mean is:

```
int* get_filled_array() {

    int* result_array = malloc(sizeof(int)*10);
    //fill it somehow...

  return result_array;
}
```

And then I set it like:

```
 int* my_array = malloc(sizeof(int)*10);
 my_array = get_filled_array();
```

Does the memory of my_array gets removed or what is happens? I quess it is wrong this way but was just wondering. 
I quess if I want to do it like this, I should create an temporary array, get the returned array of (get_filled_array() and then set my_array and the temporary equal, so I can later free the memory of both?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do

```
my_array = malloc(...);
my_array = ...;
```

The old value of `my_array` (the address of the block allocated by `malloc`) is overwritten and lost. This is called a ["memory leak"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak) (it can't be `free`d because the program doesn't know where it is anymore).

If you want to do it like that, just use

```
int *my_array = get_filled_array();
```

There's no need to call `malloc` twice.

Answer (score 3):

There will be a memory leak because the address of the memory allocated in statement

```
int* my_array = malloc(sizeof(int)*10);
```

will be lost after this assignment

```
my_array = get_filled_array();
```

And the memory previously allocated can not be freed.

Thus before calling `get_filled_array` you have to free the already allocated memory

```
int* my_array = malloc(sizeof(int)*10);
//...
free( my_array );
my_array = get_filled_array();
```

Answer (score 0):

Render unto `free(.)` everything `malloc(.)` rendered unto thee.

That is, you must call `free(.)` on anything you got from `malloc(.)`.

Your code fails to `free(.)` the pointer returned by the first `malloc(.)`

Code like this:

```
 int * my_array = get_filled_array();

 //All code using `my_arrray` must in or called from this section...


 free(my_array);
```

Consider calling the function `malloc_filled_array(.)` so its action in allocating memory is obvious.

If you're just zero filling you will probably prefer to use `calloc(.)` that does it for you and on many platforms will be more efficient if that matters.

NB: You also need to call `free(.)` on values returned by `calloc(.)` and `realloc(.)`.

Finally, it can sometimes be acceptable to just let the program end without calling `free(.)` and you're assured the run-time / operating system will just recover any allocated memory during termination. If you do that in a program that has a loop it might keep allocating more memory and run out even though it isn't really using everything it allocated.

It is not a recommended strategy unless absolutely necessary as it tends to mask leak problems with the program.